# How to format yaxis value with millions and billion initial letter in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I format my y-axis values so that they render like the followings?

**$0M, $500M, $1B, $1.5B, $2B, etc**

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/xdLacn6m/1/

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  title: { text: yaxisTitle },
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      if(this.chart.series[0].name === "Target Enterprise Value" || this.chart.series[0].name === "IPO Proceeds") {
        return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, '', ', ') + 'M' 
      } else {
        return this.value + '%'
      }
    },
    style: { color: '#2B2B2B' }
  },
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0,
  lineColor: '#2B2B2B',
  lineWidth: 1
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick inline ternary conditional did the trick

```
return '$' + (this.value / 1000 < 1 ? this.value + 'M' : this.value / 1000 + 'B')
```

in context:

```
if (this.chart.series[0].name === "Target Enterprise Value" || this.chart.series[0].name === "IPO Proceeds") {
  return '$' + (this.value / 1000 < 1 ? this.value + 'M' : this.value / 1000 + 'B')
} else {
  return this.value + '%'
}
```

@jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kinglish/0bzqs3yx/7/